# Get link to category

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using below variables to display category name.

```
<?php $postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo esc_html($postcat[0]->name );  ?>
```

How i can get link to category?

Example: www.example.com/category/business

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, You can used [`get_category_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) function.

```
// Get the URL of this category
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code, that will do the work for you :

```
   $categories = get_the_category();
   if ( ! empty( $categories ) ) 
   {
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $categories[0]->term_id ) ) . '">' . esc_html( $categories[0]->name ) . '</a>';
    }
```

Comment: No, no - I need to add href="" to <?php echo esc_html($postcat[0]->name );  ?>

Comment: It will show you the categories with the link, but it will show all the categories. Do you want to show only first one?

Comment: I want to link category of current post in my list of last 3 posts, i have something like this: https://imgur.com/a/IjWr7oGI need to a href="example.com/category/name-category">

Comment: My answer will do that, what exactly you need, please checkout with the code, if any issue, let me know I will give you the related answers.

Comment: Hmm, how? Check again please my screenshot https://imgur.com/a/IjWr7oG, its not possible to do it with that code.. I need something like permalink not list of categories

Comment: write the code inside the loop, or you can pass the post id as parameter of the "get_the_category" function